# Monitoring mailbox-size metric of routee actors with kamon-akka 0.6.x

Tags: scala, akka, akka-monitoring, kamon

I was using version **0.5.2** of **kamon-akka** library, without any problems, to monitor my akka actors. I then upgraded it to **0.6.3** and noticed that some statistics were not sent.

When I looked at the source code of kamon, I saw that the ***mailbox-size*** metric was not sent for routee actors running under a router. Instead, router metrics such as *routingTime* are being sent for the routee actors. However, I'm using them as workers and need to monitor their mailbox sizes.

Here is the part of kamon source which creates a routee monitor with *RouterMetrics* instead of *ActorMetrics* which contains the mailbox-size metric:

```
package akka.kamon.instrumentation
object ActorMonitor {
  ...

  def createRouteeMonitor(cellInfo: CellInfo): ActorMonitor = {
    def routerMetrics = Kamon.metrics.entity(RouterMetrics, cellInfo.entity)

    if (cellInfo.isTracked)
      new TrackedRoutee(cellInfo.entity, routerMetrics)
    else ActorMonitors.ContextPropagationOnly
  }

  ...
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but how can I solve this problem? Are there any configurations or workaround solutions to fix it?

Thank you in advance.